# Quick question on parallax and parsec

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, sun, stars, parallax

I know that 1 parsec (pc) is the distance of star at which 1 AU subtends 1 arcsecond.

so $1 pc = \frac{1 AU}{1"}$

Now, if two stars in a binary with a **separation of 3"** and have a **trigonometric parallax of 0.1"**, what does it mean and what's the difference?

[image]

Comment: You can use the parallax info to estimate how far the system is from earth. Then use the separation to figure out how far apart the binary is.  Then use the rest of the info to answer the question about masses.

Comment: I'm just confused about why there are 2 angles, $\theta = 0.1"$ and $\theta = 3"$, what's the difference?

Comment: 0.1" is the parallax (based on earth's movement) and 3" is how far apart the two stars are from each other.

Comment: 3" is how far the stars are apart, from where?

Comment: From each other.

Comment: Yes, but where is the observation point?

Comment: Observed from earth's orbit around the sun at the point in time were the stars show the most separation.  The max possible error (+/- radius of earth's orbit) introduced between the parallax observations and the separation observation is very small.

Comment: Ok, now I'm even more confused.

Comment: There is a background of relatively fixed stars. You see a pair of stars 3" apart. Six months later they are still 3" apart, but the pair of them together appear to have moved 1" against the background. The movement against the background is the parallax.

Comment: I see, so referring to this picture,

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Stellarparallax2.svg/263px-Stellarparallax2.svg.png

due to the motion of the earth around the sun, the binary pair of stars "appear to move" with respect to the fixed background of stars with a parallax angle of $0.1''$, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

"trigonometric parallax of 0.1" " means the stars are 10 parsecs or 33 light years from Earth.

"separation of 3" " means that an isosceles triangle with Earth at one vertex and the two stars at the other two vertices, has a very short side connecting the two stars and the angle with Earth at its vertex is 3".

Therefore, the distance between the two stars is $2\sin(1.5'') \times 33$ light years.